# ASP.NET 5: Huge response time in empty project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I installed latest ASP.NET 5 beta 8 and created simple project. After running my application I noticed that my app loading is too slow. I opened debugging tools in Chrome browser and found that all requests to controllers and even requests too smallest static file takes way to long. **All request has TTFB over 1 second!!!!**

I tried to load single file in new tab (to avoid parallel loading issues) using url to file http://localhost:57111/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/css/bootstrap-touch-carousel.css. That is about 1 kilbyte of size. And even this single file loads about second.

I tried using IIS and Kestrel as a server, tried Debug and Release modes - nothing changed.

Other my web application (for example build on Meteor platform) works perfectly on an port with TTFB about 5-10ms

PS: server and client browser are all on the same computer

PPS: I'm on Windows 10

That's the problem with the default project in the new ASP.NET vNext?

Comment: Have you tried publishing the project to IIS and run it there (without VS attached)? I've experienced similar behavior while developing in IIS Express (REST API invocation time around 1sec - just returning a constant string) but then after moving the project into dev environment on IIS the times are much like tens of miliseconds in my case...

Comment: I created a new web application (beta 8, MVC, Individual User Accounts for authentication), ran it in Chrome from within VS (debug, IIS Express) and I'm seeing TTFB around 130-150ms for the controller action responses.  I am also running Windows 10.

Comment: We're working on improving the performance of ASP.NET. You can see the latest benchmark results [here](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks). What DNX version are you using? Also, can you share the entire project you're using?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC default project template. Also I found that if to setup variable ASPNET_ENV in project settings to "Production" then everything works like a charm with TTFB 5-10ms, but the problem in debugging mode persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is caused by browser link, see [Browserlink make website slow. 1000ms is added for secondary requests](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/202)

Comment: Yeah, that is the source of this problem. As I can see it is already fixed, but it didn't get into beta8